# How do I resize a virtual disk AND map that in a vagrant environment?

Tags: virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine, vagrant

I don't know if I worded my question correctly, but I'll do my best to explain my problem here.

I've been working on resizing a virtual disk for a server my company uses. It recently filled to the brim and I was tasked to resize the virtualbox. I followed [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659005/how-to-resize-a-virtualbox-vmdk-file) on how to resize the disk, I formatted it, and everything seemed to be working.  Now all I had to do was tell Vagrant to look at the newly resized virtual disk, and everything would have been up and running. But this is where I ran into issues...

I followed a guide also on stack overflow/superuser stack exchange (I can't find the link atm, I'll post it here once I find it again) which told me to put the UUID for the virtual disk in the `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` file. I think this should have told vagrant to look at the new disk, but when I rebooted the server, Vagrant seemed to still use the old disk, as it was exhibiting the same behavior the old server was (it would be up for a few seconds and then freeze).

How can I get Vagrant to look at the larger disk instead of the original one?